# Join data table with latest value, if not found show null mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, which every table has it's own foreign key and primary key.

Table scheme looks like this :

```
tbl_cake
/---------------------------------------------------------------------------\
| CakeId (Primary key) | CakeName       | UserId (Foreign Key from tbl_user) |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1                   | BlackForest    | 12345                              |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  2                   | Fruit Pie      | 98475                              |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  3                   | Birthday Cake  | 12345                              |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  4                   | Raspberry Pie  | 28475                              |
\----------------------------------------------------------------------------/


tbl_user
/--------------------------------------\
| UserId (Primary key)   | UserName    |  
|--------------------------------------|
|  12345                 | Angelia     | 
|--------------------------------------|
|  98475                 | Rudi        | 
|--------------------------------------|
|  56782                 | Andika      | 
\--------------------------------------/


tbl_transaction
/--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
| TransactionId(Primary) | CakeId(Foreign) | UserId| Qty  | Date                     | OrderType   |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1                     | 1               | 12345 | 1000 | 2020-04-01 10:05:01      | Drive Thru  |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  2                     | 2               | 98475 | 200  | 2020-04-03 09:15:01      | On The Spot |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  3                     | 2               | 98475 | 500  | 2020-04-03 11:05:01      | On The Spot |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  4                     | 1               | 12345 | 150  | 2020-04-05 08:05:01      | On The Spot |
\--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

So the goals are :

Show UserId,TransactionId,Qty,Date and OrderType which :

1. Show all UserId, either it has any order or not.
2. If multiple order occurs, then show the latest data
3. If UserId don't have any order, fill the missing values with null
4. Finally, show the data with OrderType 'On The Spot'.

The expected result will be :

```
FINAL RESULT
/----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
| UserId         | TransactionId   | Qty   | Date                     | OrderType  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  12345         | 4               | 150   | 2020-04-05 08:05:01      | On The Spot|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  98475         | 3               | 500   | 2020-04-03 11:05:01      | On The Spot|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  56782         | null            | null  | null                     | null       |
\----------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

I think using join(s) will accomplish this, but i'm not sure how, especially when determine if UserId has any order or not, and pick the latest order to be shown.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it (using left join and max function) :

```
select tbl_user.UserId,tbl_transaction.TransactionId,tbl_transaction.Qty,tbl_transaction.Date,
tbl_transaction.OrderType 

from tbl_cake 
left join tbl_user on tbl_user.UserId=tbl_cake.UserId 
left join tbl_transaction on tbl_user.UserId=tbl_transaction.UserId 
and 
tbl_transaction.Date=(select max(Date) from tbl_transaction where UserId=tbl_User.UserId 
and tbl_transaction.OrderType="On The Spot") 
group by UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, we would use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM tbl_transaction
    WHERE OrderType = 'On The Spot'
)

SELECT
    u.UserId,
    t.TransactionId,
    t.Qty,
    t.Date,
    t.OrderType
FROM tbl_user u
LEFT JOIN cte t
    ON u.UserId = t.UserId AND rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Hello Tim, thanks for the reply. Does it mean UserId '56782' will not appear?. I tried Fiddle Demo but no UserId with '56782' appeared.

Comment: @AndikaTrisnaAdhi Sorry, I have edited the answer a few times, find the working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=b626f0d658d49abf4c516a959492d44f).

Comment: currently my machine doesn't have Mysql 8, nor MariaDB 10.2.1. So 'WITH' function is not available. I managed to solve my answer (googled couple hours for sure) by using left join and max value. 

Anyway thanks, i've never heard about 'PARTITION', ROW_NUMBER() or CTE though.

Comment: Fair enough.  Queries on earlier versions of MySQL can be verbose, which is why I try to avoid writing them `:-)`